# What is the process flow of calculation while we add product to cart in Magento

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

What is the process flow of price calculation of product while we add a new product to cart in Magento. I have to consider following prices in order to clarify/ Debug the issues.

1. Catalog Price Rule.
2. Group Price of product.
3. Tier Price
4. Special Price.
5. Shopping cart price rule.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I would like to point out that Shopping cart price rule different from all others.

In Magento, the ***lowest amount of below prices*** will be used as the ***cart price*** whenever a product is cart.

- **Catalog Price Rule.**
- **Group Price of product**
- **Tier Price**
- **Special Price.**

---

### Example:

Suppose, product prices are like

- **Catalog Price Rule.**  is 200
- **Group Price of product** is 150
- **Tier Price**  is 175
- **Special Price.** is 210

In this case, Magento will use ***Group price of product*** since which is the ***lowest  amount  of all prices*** as per above example. Hence the cart price will be 150.

**Shopping Cart Price Rule** is applied to the price that you have already in a shopping cart. Hence Price Rules has no direct relationship with above specified price items.