# Need clarification - 1

Tags: certification

If the product price is $50 and the tier price is $40 for 3 products and catalog rule applied is $5 flat off for that product. What will be the final product price?

Select one:

a. $35

b. $45

c. $50

d. $40

Please suggest right answer with explanation.

Comment: you can easily check this question by creating local env and code. Don't expose any real question.

Comment: I hope this is not an actual question from the exam.

Comment: Yea this is not from real exam question as I didn't attempt any real exam till now

Comment: If the quantity is less then 3 then the product price will be B) $45 AND if the product quantity is equal or greater then 3 then the product price will be $40.

Answer (score 5):

The lowes price is applayed.
So if you buy 1 it will be $45 with catalog price rule.
If you buy 3 it will be $40.

Question is about product price, so I think $45.

In extra scenerio when is applayed cart rule this will add discount to already calculated price.

Helpful answer:
[What is the process flow of calculation while we add product to cart in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86669/what-is-the-process-flow-of-calculation-while-we-add-product-to-cart-in-magento)

Answer (score 4):

1. Price is $50
2. Tier price is $40 for 3 products men if you buy 3 or more products then the price will be $40 for each product.
3. Catalog rule applied is $5 flat off for that product men in cart price this amount will be deducted.

if qty less then 2 then qty multiply $50 and Flat off applied and qty over 3 then qty multiplay $40 and Flat off apply.

Comment: Minimum price will take first priority always, so if you have original price $50 and discounted price is $5 than final price will be $45, tier price will not affect here because its higher than discounted price, if your tier price had $4 than than final price would be $4